# SSH without password does not work after upgrading from 18.04 to 22.04

Tags: ssh, password, 22.04

SSH without password does not work after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 22.04. The client is Ubuntu 22.04 and the server is Ubuntu 14.04. Using Ubuntu 18.04 as client works correctly.

I have done the correct steps of generating the key in .ssh and copying it to the server, but in Ubuntu 22.04 it does not work

Summary of the steps I have always performed and have always worked:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -p 1331 user@server 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Is this a Seahorse problem? In Seahorse in Ubuntu 22.04 I can't find the option "The owner of this key is authorized to connect to this computer" that if it is in 18.04. I don't know if this may have something to do with it

Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: Question?
Is HOSTNAME on all pc the same? If you set manual DNS, is it DNS the same on all PC?
Check command ssh-keyscan flag. And not sure what ssh command/flag refresh keys to load in SSH that can work. it might ssh-add

Comment: HOSTNAME are different in client and server, but I never use hostname or dns, I use the ip directly, the local ip of the server is fixed, ej --> ssh -p 1234 nameUser@192.168.1.22

Comment: If you are not familiar with hostname and DNS try to look them up. I had some issues long time a ago, also without using them at any point. For some reason, ssh didn't like if all are not the same. And check ssh-add ( I think ) is to reload ssh-agent. Try:
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" Might flag will be different

Comment: I have found the solution here
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html
Cause
The RSA SHA-1 hash algorithm is being quickly deprecated 
I have added to /etc/ssh/ssh_config on the client side the following line --> PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 SSH the RSA key isn't working since upgrading from 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409105/ubuntu-22-04-ssh-the-rsa-key-isnt-working-since-upgrading-from-20-04)

Comment: There is a Ubuntu 14.04 server in this question which makes it off topic. Ubuntu 14.04 went EOL in April 30th 2019.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The RSA SHA-1 hash algorithm is being quickly deprecated. There is a workaround for re-enabling RSA at [SSH-RSA key rejected with message "no mutual signature algorithm"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html) .

> To fully resolve this issue, our team recommends that these deprecated SSH keys be regenerated using a supported and more secure algorithm such as ECDSA and ED25519. SSH keys generated with either ECDSA or ED25519 algorithms are not affected by RSA deprecation.

Add the following line to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client side:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

Comment: I've tried a lot of solutions, nothing worked! This was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks a lot. 

Comment: To login without a password on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I had to add an additional line:  `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`.  And that entry, along with the entry mentioned in the answer above, are placed at the tail-end of the stanza for `Host *`

Comment: Rather than use a deprecated algorithm, create new keys using ED25519

ssh-keygen -t ecdsa

ED25519 is generally considered more secure than RSA

Answer (score 7):

*Update: I suggest trying the command-line lower down to see if the configuration changes proposed will actually work, that way you'll only be making config changes if you've already checked that they'll work.*

**tl;dr** - Add these lines to an ssh config file (personal one typically in `.ssh/config` or system-wide one in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) if you're having this issue connecting to machines (say) `alice.example.com` and `bob.example.org`,

```
Host alice.example.com bob.example.org
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

**or in more detail:**

SSH on Ubuntu and Linux in general normally refers to OpenSSH which now deprecates (and [disables](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8) by default) the RSA SHA-1 algorithm. It's still available but has to be enabled for the hosts that need it, see [their explainer](https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html),

> When an SSH client connects to a server, each side offers lists of connection parameters to the other... For a successful connection, there must be at least one mutually-supported choice for each parameter.

To be able to connect to hosts with this issue, either or both of the above options are needed (and it's recommended to upgrade the hosts so that they no longer need to use this now-considered-insecure algorithm). In some circumstances you may want to enable these options for all hosts (`Host *`).

When you try connecting to a machine, if you see this error message,

```
Unable to negotiate with ... port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
```

that can be fixed with `HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`

When you try connecting to a machine, if you see this error message,

```
username@some.hostname: Permission denied (publickey).
```

that may be fixed with `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`

Putting that together gives you a stanza like this (in this case for 2 machines),

```
Host alice.example.com bob.example.org
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

You need to add that stanza to either a personal .ssh config file (create it if it doesn't exist) typically in `.ssh/config` under your home directory, or if you want any user on your machine to have these settings, add the stanza to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

If you don't want to make any configuration changes, you can specify the options on the command line instead,

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -oPubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa some.hostname
```

Finally to note that the `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` keyword supercedes `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` mentioned in some answers (see "Bugfixes" section in the [changelog](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.5))

Answer (score 5):

You can add the following line to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` if you want the add this config for all users or to `~/.ssh/config` if you want to add this to your own user.

> HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

Comment: This did the trick for me for connecting to Unifi switches and AP's without password.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` SSH option:

```
ssh -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa foo@old_server
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/(your key filename)
```

Then test:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
```

It has been OK.