# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS SSH Server refuses auth key, works fine on 20.04 LTS

Tags: ssh

Server refused out key problem in 22.04LTS. The same procedure works fine in 20.04LTS.

public key is in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. change mode is correct.

Comment: Is this afresh installation or a release upgrade?

Comment: check permissions on ~ssh and files in it

Comment: Are you logging in with an AD account ? I see you already checked permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH without password does not work after upgrading from 18.04 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404049/ssh-without-password-does-not-work-after-upgrading-from-18-04-to-22-04)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to use ECDSA algorithm for creating the keypair.

You can create it with this command: `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521`
(521 is the maximum and recommended key size).

I learned this was needed from a comment in [this DO article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-22-04).

Comment: Other solutions to the same issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404049/ssh-without-password-does-not-work-after-upgrading-from-18-04-to-22-04